# Undefined reference to `SHA1'

Tags: c, windows, openssl, codeblocks, sha1

I'm posting here due to a problem with Code::Blocks

I've recently created a project in linux which compiled and executed correctly.
Now I am trying to made it work on windows.

**Problem**

When I tried to compile thanks to Code::Blocks I received the error :
    C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Collector\verification.c
    |44|undefined reference to `SHA1'|

Here is my configuration :

- Right click on my project
- Then "Build options"

In "Linker setting" i've got : 
 -lws2_32 into the "Other linker options".

In the "Search directories" tab i've got :

In "Compiler" :

> ..\..\..\..\OpenSSL-Win64\include

which corresponds to my include file of Open SSL install

> In Linker : ..\..\..\..\OpenSSL-Win64\lib

Correspond to lib of Open SSL

And here an extract from the C code who got compilation problem :

```
    bool checkVol(Index* index, unsigned char* vol, int id_vol) {
        char outsha[40] = { 0 };
        unsigned char outbuf[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

        SHA1(vol, sizeof(vol), outbuf);

        hexToString(outbuf, outsha);

        printf("%s\n", outsha);
        printf("%s\n", index->sha[id_vol]);

        if ( strcmp(outsha, index->sha[id_vol]) == 0 ) {
            printf("Volume %i is the same.\n", id_vol);
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

I don't know what should I do next to make my program work on windows...
Does someone know the good configuration?

Thanks for your help.

PS : Sorry for my probably bad english :x

Comment: you also need a `-lcrypto` to link to the `SHA1` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I've tried your solution and got an error : 
"ld.exe||cannot find -lcrypto|"

Comment: Then the search path to the lib file is incorrect, as that's the name of the OpenSSL library containing the SHA1 routine.

Comment: Then i dont know what to try ... i cant find how to correct this problem.
I've tried to edit all the setting and nothing works. 
After seek i've got no "libcrypto.*" into my "OpenSSL-Win64" directory :/

Comment: Ok so i succeed into made this thing work : I Edit my post

Comment: The solution should be posted as an answer, not edited into your question. (Yes, you can post an answer to your own question.)

Comment: Ok then i'm going to edit that thanks :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this by my own.

**Fix :**

So first i've removed the x64 version
Then install the "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1L" from [this link](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Then update my build option with the following configuration :

In "linker setting" i've added : the 2 '.a' from

```
"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\MinGW\"
```

Update "Search directories" by putting :

```
"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include"
```

in "Compiler" tab.

Hope that's will help other people ! :D