# undefined reference to `SHA1' in C

Tags: c, sha1, dev-c++

I'm trying to compile this code written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl\sha.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
char data[] = "Hello, world!";
size_t length = strlen(data);

unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1(data, length, hash);
}
```

I'm using Dev-C++. It gives me the error : undefined reference to `SHA1'.
I founded this post: 
[Undefined reference to `SHA1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752994/undefined-reference-to-sha1)
but I didn't solve the problem.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to link in a library that supplies the SHA1 function, the linker setting parts of the answer that you've linked to.

Comment: I have already added the 2 '.a' in linker setting, what more?

Comment: You must not have done it correctly.

Comment: I just went to Project -> Project Option -> Parameters -> Add Library and selected the two '.a'

Answer (score 2):

MrCaptain Alex, Rup and Barmar wrote what is the correct way, but in my case, I have Ubuntu, when I link, It's necesary add the library `-L/usr/lib -lcrypto`:

```
$ gcc -o executable_file source_file.c -L/usr/lib -lcrypto
```

That's all ;-)